# Finding the centre of the largest inscribed circle in an irregular polygon

Tags: polygons

[edited title]

I need to find A centre point of an irregular polygon.

Being an irregular polygon, I'm aware that there can be no geometric centre.

I have a very specific shape in mind, it is a pentagon with 2 long sides and 3 short.

The internal angles are aporox 4× 114.8125 and 1× 80.75 (which is between the 2 longer sides).

What I need to calculate, assuming that the acute angle is at the top, and the middle short side at the base, is at what point along the height of the shape would be the centre point for the largest circle I can inscribe within the shape?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You'd better title with "center of the largest inscribed circle".

Comment: The largest such circle touches at least three sides. These three sides form a triangle (extended if needed) with the circle the incrscribed or escribed circle of the triangle. Pick the circle with the **smallest** radius.